# Adhesive for small pebbles.

Tags: adhesives

I'm going to build a small birdhouse and plan on having small pea sized gravel adhered to the outside walls. What is the best way to go for adhesive? Is there a good glue in a bottle that can withstand outside temperatures and last a couple years? TiA[image: picture is example only]

Comment: The birdhouse material is wood and then the stones will be glued to the walls, do I have that right?

Comment: You are correct Erica. Just wanna know if a glue will do the job, or if I have to go epoxy, etc.